# Cannot terminate a shell command with Ctrl+c

Tags: bash, shell, terminate, sigint

Would someone please tell me why below `bash` statement cannot be terminated by <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> properly?

```
$( { ( tail -fn0 /tmp/a.txt & )| while read line; do echo $line; done } 3>&1 )
```

I run this statement, then two `bash` processes and one `tail` process are launched(got from `ps auxf`), then input <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>, and it won't quit to the `bash` prompt, at this moment, I see the two `bash` processes stopped, while the `tail` is still running, then I input something into `/tmp/a.txt`, then we could get into bash prompt.

What I want is, input <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>, then just quit into `bash` prompt without any relevant process left.

It will be more appreciative that someone explains the exact process of this statement, like a pipe causes the bash fork, something redirect to somewhere, etc.

**Updated at Oct 9 2014:**

Here provide some update in case it's useful to you.
My adopt solution is alike with 2 factors:

1. use a tmp pid file

   ```
   ( tail -Fn0 ${monitor_file} & echo "$!" >${tail_pid} ) | \
   while IFS= read -r line; do 
       xxxx
   done
   ```
2. use trap like: `trap "rm ${tail_pid} 2>/dev/null; kill 0 2>/dev/null; exit;" INT TERM` to kill relevant processes and remove remain files.

Please note, this `kill 0 2` is bash specific, and 0 means all processes in the current process group. 
This solution used a tmp pid file, while I still expect other solution without tmp pid file.

Comment: Why are you running it with `$(...)`? That's for command substitution.

Comment: "tail -fn0 /tmp/a.txt &" starts a new process in background (due to &), so it is not affected by ctrl+c of the main process.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%28%7B+%28+tail+-fn0+%2Ftmp%2Fa.txt+%26+%29%7C+while+read+line%3B+do+echo+%24line%3B+done+%7D+3%3E%261%3B%7D%29

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I know the $() seems useless here, just to trigger this issue to study.

Comment: While since the tail running in background, why can't I get to the bash prompt after the ctrl+c? That's my concern.

Comment: because it is a separate process from the main one, isolated, with its own pid. It lives its own life ! ctrl+c will kill the main process but not its child process. You have to manage the life of this child process. To me, the best approach would be to write a "service myscript [stop|start]" (or the same with init.d), so that you could handle stop and kill child process, for that you will have to get the child pid in your main process

Comment: Thanks for your response! Let me explain more:

Comment: Like this: kill $( { ( tail -fn0 ${monitor_file} & echo "$!" >&3 ) | while read -r line; do echo "${line}";  done } 3>&1)           I redirect the pid of tail, and use $() for killing the tail, while the ctrl+c and not interrupt the statement properly.

Comment: well, i will go to bed now, it is 4am here ! what are you exactly trying to do ? maybe we should review the whole approach !

Comment: Good night my remote friend. While I'm writing a script to monitor a log file, once certain string pattern is occuring in the log, it need stop monitoring and take some othen action. When the action is done, it need monitor log again, loop like this. This script is supposed to be able to clean all the process and temporary files created by itself once it's interrupted. Actually, I just want to study the exact process of this shell statement. For knowledge. Is it possible just quit after a ctrl-c like normal routine?

Comment: I wonder if this behaviour is to do with bash's way of handling a pipeline and collecting the status of every process in the pipeline. Classically, only the last process in a pipeline was a child of the shell, so when the last process exited, the others were left parentless.  However, since `bash` waits (or can wait) for all children (so the statuses are collected in the `PIPESTATUS` array), which means that the 'pipeline' doesn't end until all processes are terminated, and `tail -f` does not terminate until it gets a SIGPIPE signal after writing something to the pipe.

Comment: You might have some luck using `trap` (for the interrupt signal) to kill tail, You might need to save the PID, which can be tricky... (`pgrep -f "tail -fn0 /tmp/a.txt"` would work, but will give problems if multiple instances are running...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works to trap the `INT` signal (sent by `Ctrl-C`) to kill the `tail` process.

```
$( r=$RANDOM; trap '{ kill $(cat /tmp/pid$r.pid);rm /tmp/pid$r.pid;exit; }' SIGINT EXIT; { ( tail -fn0 /tmp/a.txt & echo $! > /tmp/pid$r.pid  )| while read line; do echo $line; done } 3>&1 )
```

(I use a random value on the PID file name to at least mostly allow multiple instances to run)